# Generate a random number with a non-uniform distribution

Tags: javascript, probability

I have a formula that generates a random integer in a given range [x,y].

```
rand = Math.floor(x + Math.random()*(y-x+1));
```

And I would like the generated integer to have a higher chance of being close to the midrange.
[Here is an interesting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120286/2514482).

I am trying to adapt that solution to my problem (numbers skewed towards the midrange, not the extremities), but I am struggling with the formula.

```
beta = Math.sin(Math.random()*Math.PI)^2;
rand = Math.floor(x + beta*(y-x+1));
```

I do not understand how `beta` works. According to [this graph](http://fooplot.com/plot/1o2b0z5bkv) wouldn't the numbers generated have a higher chance of being closer to 0.5? `beta` always returns the same number. Didn't I implement `Math.random()` properly? I swear javascript is messing with me right now.

Comment: `^2` is not what you expect but a bit `XOR`. You need `Math.pow(..., 2)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a

```
beta = 4 * (rand - 0.5)^3 + 0.5
```

function or something with a similar shape

[Graph](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoKHgtMC41KV4zKSo0KzAuNSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwRkYxNSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDZGRkYifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRkYwMEY3In0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6IiIsImNvbG9yIjoiI0ZGMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIjAiLCIxIiwiLTAuNSIsIjEuNSJdLCJncmlkIjpbIjEiLCIxIl0sInNpemUiOls3MDAsNDAwXX1d)

Distribution results: http://jsfiddle.net/4hBqz/