# Create a normal distribution-looking pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create lines that look more like hand-drawn lines by adding randomness to them. I currently use this formula to modify the coordinates

```
x-10+Math.floor(Math.random()*20)
```

This random distribution is linear, I would like to use something that makes it more likely to hit the target. `X` according to something that looks like, but doesn't have to be a bell-curve. How can this be done?

Comment: https://github.com/errcw/gaussian

Comment: You can define a bell curve as an array of points (for example) and randomly pick from that array. But that is a bit brute force, [are you looking for something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582882/javascript-math-random-normal-distribution-gaussian-bell-curve)

Comment: Many alternatives there, most are complex or voted down because they are incorrect. I only need something that looks a bit bell-curve-ish, it's not to specific. Does anyone have a sugestion?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29325069/251311

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the probability density function that defines the standard normal distribution:

```
function stdNormalDistribution (x) {
  return Math.pow(Math.E,-Math.pow(x,2)/2)/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI);
}
```

The function is symmetric around 0, which means `stdNormalDistribution(x) == stdNormalDistribution(-x).`

**Source:** [Wikipedia: Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Normal_distribution&oldid=654906054)

Comment: With ES6 exponentiation, `Math.E**(-(x**2)/2)/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)`