# Non-uniform (biased towards a value) random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I am aware that random integers can be generated in JavaScript like this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

But what I want is a set of random numbers that are biased towards a specific value.

As an example, if my specific center value is 200, I want a set of random numbers that has a large range, but mostly around 200. Hopefully there will be a function like

`biasedRandom(center, biasedness)`

Comment: This sounds more like a [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com) problem than a programming problem.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there will be a built in way of doing this. I won't get that if this was on the math forum.

Comment: What do you mean by "mostly"? At least 50% of the time these are close to 200? And how close is close?

Comment: @MinusFour hopefully there will be a function like `biasedRandom(center, biasedness)` ?

Comment: Duplicate of this question, although there could be many other ways to do this than the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325069/how-to-generate-random-numbers-biased-towards-one-value-in-a-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a Gaussian distribution might be about right here.

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582882/javascript-math-random-normal-distribution-gaussian-bell-curve) describes how to produce something that is Gaussian in shape. We can then scale and shift the distribution by two factors;

- The mean (200 in this case) which is where the distribution is centred
- The variance which gives control over the width of the distribution

I have included a histogram of the generated numbers (using plotly) in my example so you can easily see how varying these two parameters `v` and `mean` affects the numbers generated. In your real code you would not need to include the plotly library.

```js
// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn_bm() {
    var u = 0, v = 0;
    while(u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
    while(v === 0) v = Math.random();
    return Math.sqrt( -2.0 * Math.log( u ) ) * Math.cos( 2.0 * Math.PI * v );
}

//generate array
// number of points
let n = 50;
// variance factor
let v = 1;
// mean
let mean = 200;
let numbers = []
for (let i=0; i<n;i++){
 numbers.push(randn_bm())
}
// scale and shift
numbers = numbers.map( function (number){ return number*v + mean})

// THIS PURELY FOR PLOTTING
var trace = {
    x: numbers,
    type: 'histogram',
  };
var data = [trace];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Although Box-Muller is really slow. If that becomes a problem, you might want to google "Ziggurat" for the current best algorithm for generating Gaussian randoms, or use something that just approximates a bell curve.

Comment: Thank you @LeeDanielCrocker